# Django admin - Is it possible to limit a user's access to only his own inputted data?

Tags: django, django-admin

In other words, I would like to disallow users from editing or viewing anything but their own inputted data, throughout all applications.

I read [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter17/) that this may be impossible with the built in admin application. If so is there an extension available?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be done.
You need to create the appropriate modelAdmin in your admin.py first.

For list "display" filtering modify the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) method:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        return Entry.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

For field filtering, depending on the field type you want to limit you override the appropriate method.

Related django documentation is here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

To limit foreignkey field output you can do something like this:
(from the django documentation)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car": # The name of the field you want to limit
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```